# How can I move this into a mixin that can be extended?

Tags: css, less

I have 2 less files:
in first file:

```
table.table-leaderboard-crucible thead tr {
  background-color: @crucible-background-color;
  color: @crucible-forefront-color;
}
```

In second file

```
  .crucible-widget {
    background-color: @crucible-background-color;
    color: @crucible-forefront-color;
  }
```

How can I make it possible that I turn the first file into a mixin that can be extended? basically reducing repeating myself with something that is already defined. I was looking at the documentation here:

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question fully but you can import the first file as `(less)` or as `(reference)` and then add `&:extend(table.table-leaderboard-crucible thead tr);` within the `.crucible-widget`.

Comment: How can I add it as a reference @Harry?

Comment: Have a look at the [Import Directives](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

I only use SASS but its almost the same in LESS so you may want to try this:

```
// the mixin
.foo (@bgcolor, @color) {
  background-color: @bgcolor;
  color: @color;
}

// call the mixin
.element {
  .foo(#000, #FFF);
}

// the result
.element {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Found it here: [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-featurehttp://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)